# JMS timestamps in 1970

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, wildfly

When sending JMS messages the JMS timestamps we see on the client are all in January of 1970.

Our code roughly looks like this:

```
try (JMSContext context = this.connectionFactory.createContext()) {  
  JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();  
  TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage(this.createMessageString());  
  producer.send(this.queue, message);  
}
```

We do not explicitly call `Message#setJMSTimestamp(long)`. It is our understanding that we should not call this method. We do not call `MessageProducer#setDisableMessageTimestamp(boolean)`.
Accessing the timestamp right after `producer.send(this.queue, message)` displays a correct timestamp.

The client is a Java SE application that looks at the messages in the queue trough a `QueueBrowser`. The client gets the JMS timestamp with:

```
new Date(message.getJMSTimestamp());
```

We are using WildFly 9.0.1 and the IBM WebSphere MQ 8.0.0.3 RAR.

Comment: Message time stamp is set by MQ. If you have access to samples that are shipped with MQ, just try sending few messages using amqsput/amqsputc and verify the time stamp on messages. This could help in isolating the problem.

Comment: _the JMS timestamps we see on the client are all in January of 1970_ : what do you mean with _the client_? what is the value in the consumer?

Comment: I added the client code.

Comment: Do you maybe call somewhere `MessageProducer.setDisableMessageTimestamp`? Can you check what is the value of the `JMSTimestamp` right after the `producer.send(this.queue, message);` line?

Comment: @Ruben we don't call `setDisableMessageTimestamp`, after `producer.send` the timestamp looks correct.